# the centreon 18 is not working with remote polller and remote servers. why?

Tags: opennms

I have been trying to install distributed monitoring environment on my network for very long time using [Centreon](https://www.centreon.com/en/) but whenever I install the remote poller or remote server, either it can't even show there or nothing happen. If someone had tried this, please let me know the step-by-step process.

**Note**: I had try every single document from he centreon but it's not working for me.

Comment: May be ask their TechSupport or post it on Centreon Slack https://www.centreon.com/en/services/techsupport/

Answer (score 1):

> 1 Network flows opening

*From:* Poller *To:* NTP server *Protocol:* NTP *Port:* UDP 123 *Application:* Synchronization of the system clock

*From:* Poller *To:* DNS server *Protocol:* DNS *Port:* UDP 53 *Application:* Domain name resolution

*From:* Poller *To:* SMTP server *Protocol:* SMTP *Port:* TCP 25 *Application:* Notification via email

*From:* Poller *To:* Repository *Protocol:* HTTP (FTP) *Port:* TCP 80 (FTP 20,21) *Application:* Repository for system and application packages

*From:* Central server *To:* Poller *Protocol:* SSH *Port:* TCP 22 *Application:* Export of Centreon configuration

> 2 Poller setup

Use the ISO Linux based on CentOS distribution or RPM packages available for CentOS distribution.

Online documentation on poller installation: https://documentation.centreon.com/docs/centreon/en/19.04/installation/from_iso.html

> 3 Exchanging SSH keys

The communication between the central server and a poller server is done via SSH. You must exchange the SSH keys between the two servers.

If you don’t have any private SSH keys on the central server for the centreon user:

```
# su - centreon
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

Copy this key to the new server:

```
# su - centreon
$ ssh-copy-id -i .ssh/id_rsa.pub centreon@IP_POLLER
```

The password of the centreon user is centreon. It can be easily changed using the passwd command.

> 4 Configure the poller in Centreon web interface

Go to the **Configuration > Pollers** menu and click on **Add server with the wizard** to configure a new poller.

Select **Add a Centreon Poller** and click on Next. Type in **the name**, **the IP address of the poller** and **IP address of the Central Server**.

Then click on **Apply** to register this new poller in Centreon.

It takes a few seconds for the wizard to configure your new poller in the system.

> 5 Monitor your host from this new poller

In the **Configuration > Host** page, you now have this poller entry in the **Monitored from** list field. Select it for each host.

According to the kind of monitoring protocol you are using for each dedicated host, don't forget to open/configure the network flow between the poller and the host (ICMP, SNMP, HTTP, ..)